# Ubuntu 18.04 not shutting down

Tags: boot, 18.04, shutdown

My laptop is not shutting down. I tried the grub edit and the power settings methods but nothing worked. I have to shut down my laptop by pressing the power button for 5 to 10 sec. It usually freezes in a listed black screen with something related to "frameware update". Also `sudo shutdown -h now` and similar commends doesn't work. Please help

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Care to share some information on your setup? Which laptop? Can you post the exact error you get?

Comment: @MrShunz Hi, Setup info- RAM- 2 GB, Processor-Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3520 @ 2.16GHz × 4, Graphics-Intel® Bay Trail, Hard Disk- 500 GB, Gnome-3.28.2, OS type- 64 bit ; Laptop Info- Acer Aspire E-1 series Model No. Z5WE3;

Comment: @MrShunz Error info- Shut down is not working. Although Shut down initiates every time, it usually leads to a screen similler to the boot screen(Ubuntu logo screen) or to a screen where some information about starting and completing certain processes are given then it freeze right there and after 4-6 sec laptops internel cooling fan speeds up while it remains freezed to those particular screen. P.S- Laptop's battery is not in a working condition I have to run my laptop with the power cord plugged in. Also Laptop freezes randomly during work but that is quite rare event. Hope info. is enough.

Comment: Same problem here. Tried everything what worked for others in previous versions..